# Java ArrayList and FileReader

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I'm really stucked on this one. I'm wondering if it's possible to exclude all the elements from arraylist on reading a file? Thank you in advance!

I have elements on my arraylist(excludelist) like this:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

And I have csv data on my file(readtest) like this:

```
test1,off
test2,on
test3,off
test4,on
```

so what i'm expecting is to exclude all the data from arraylist in while loop then will be output like this :

> test4,on

This is my code:

```
String exclude = "C:\\pathtomyexcludefile\\exclude.txt";    
String read = "C:\\pathtomytextfile\\test.txt";

                   File readtest = new File(read);
                   File excludetest = new File(exclude);

                    ArrayList<String> excludelist = new ArrayList();
                    excludelist.addAll(getFile(excludetest));

    try{
            String line;
                    LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(readtest,"UTF-8");
                    while(it.hasNext()){
            line = it.nextLine();
            //determine here

            }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    public static ArrayList<String> getFile(File file) {
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList();
            String line;
              try{
                LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file,"UTF-8");
                    while(it.hasNext()){
                        line = it.nextLine();
                        data.add(line);     
                 }
                    it.close();
              }

                          catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
          return data;
        }
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What have you done to debug so far?

Answer (score 1):

There might be more efficient ways to do this, but you can inspect each line you're reading using `String.startsWith` against each element in the `excludeList`. If the line does not start with a to-be-excluded word, add it to the `approvedLines` list.

```
String exclude = "C:\\pathtomyexcludefile\\exclude.txt";    
String read = "C:\\pathtomytextfile\\test.txt";

File readtest = new File(read);
File excludetest = new File(exclude);

List<String> excludelist = new ArrayList<>();
excludelist.addAll(getFile(excludetest));
List<String> approvedLines = new ArrayList<>();

LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(readtest, "UTF-8");

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String line = it.nextLine();
    boolean lineIsValid = true;
    for (String excludedWord : excludelist) {
        if (line.startsWith(excludedWord)) {
            lineIsValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (lineIsValid) {
        approvedLines.add(line);
    }
}

// check that we got it right
for (String line : approvedLines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: I can't do this one, I can't put the line on memory. I'm reading big file text here.

Answer (score 0):

If your excluded elements are a a `String` objects, you can try something like this:

```
while(it.hasNext()){
    line = it.nextLine();
    for(String excluded : excludelist){
        if(line.startsWith(excluded)){
            continue;
        }
    }  
}
```